# How to fetch metric details per component (file) with Sonarqube APIs

Tags: sonarqube

I need to get the value of a few metrics for a specific component (a specific java class) for each analysis.

As an example, I need to get something like:

| Analysis | Component | Complexity | ncloc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| f1234 | /mypackage/a.java | 10 | 150 |
| f1235 | /mypackage/a.java | 10 | 155 |

I can get the details of the metric, I guess related to the last analysis.

Here is the API call I am using for the details. As an example, I can get

- Metrics: complexity and ncloc
- componentKey:  org:apache:zookeper2:src/java/main/org/apache/zookeeper/server/quorum/AuthFastLeaderElection.java
  http://sonar63.rd.tut.fi/api/measures/component?metricKeys=complexity,ncloc&componentKey=org:apache:zookeper2:src/java/main/org/apache/zookeeper/server/quorum/AuthFastLeaderElection.java

Does anybody know how to get the same metrics for all the analysis or for a specific analysis?
I might get the list of analysis with the api http://sonar63.rd.tut.fi/api/project_analyses/search?project=org:apache:zookeper2&ps=500 but I cannot find a way to pass the analysis id to the measures api.

Answer (score 0):

You should try `api/measures/search_history` endpoint. You should be able to reach documentation at `<sonarqube_instance_url>/web_api/api/measures/search_history`.

Comment: Thank you @raspy! It works at the project level. 
As example, it works for 
http://sonar63.rd.tut.fi/api/measures/search_history?metrics=complexity,ncloc&component=org:apache:zookeper2 

But I cannot find a way to use it at file level. If I add the component name instead of the project name I do not get the history of measures: http://sonar63.rd.tut.fi/api/measures/search_history?metrics=complexity,ncloc&component=org:apache:zookeper2:src/java/main/org/apache/zookeeper/server/quorum/AuthFastLeaderElection.java